# Multiprocessing on a set number of cores

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

In the code below, where `Function` is a function to be called, how might I specify the number of processors to be used as 10?

```
  if __name__ == '__main__':
        jobs = []

        for l in lst:
           p = multiprocessing.Process(target=Function, args=(l,))
           jobs.append(p)
           p.start()
```

This code will completely take over my server, so how do I limit it to ten cores? Should I put it in a loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that you are essentially mapping a function over a list of variables might I suggest that you use [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) instead.

This is a class which creates a pool of a limited number of worker threads that can then be used to run a function over a list of inputs instead of `Process` where you create a thread per function call and then run them all at the same time

An example of using it in versions of python < 3.3 would be:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import contextlib

num_threads = 10

with contextlib.closing( Pool(num_threads) ) as pool:
    results = pool.map(Function, lst)
```

If you are using python 3 than the `Pool` class can use a context manager by default and the code simplifies to:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

num_threads = 10

with Pool(num_threads) as pool:
    results = pool.map(lst)
```

Comment: Is `o` here a file which is opened each time that the function is called? If so I guess what might be happening is that any writes that are buffered to it aren't getting flushed to disk. Try adding a `o.flush()` call after you call `o.write()`. If it's not that I'd have to see the code of your function to give more specific advice.

Answer (score 0):

Use a process pool to allocate set number of processes to do your task: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers